# When pulling a webpage in Java how can you make sure the AJAX calls are complete

Tags: java, ajax, http

When making a webpage call like:

```
URL redfinURL = new URL("http://www.facebook.com");
        URLConnection conn = redfinURL.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        Reader isReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Is there a way to not pull back the page until it's entirely rendered?

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "rendered". There's no rendering occurring. If you mean you don't want it as a stream ... don't use the `getInputStream()` method.

Comment: no where it seems to be ajax call, as this is pure java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @monrgano said its not going to work with `URLConnections`, try with [`WebDriver`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) they support javascript and they can execute javascripts (your ajax) on browsers

Answer (score 2):

`URLConnection` is not a browser, it doesn't execute any Javascript or the like, it only gets the resource in a given URL (html, js, css...)